# Are absolute or root-relative internal links better for SEO?

Tags: seo, html, links

Does website seo score changes the way writing internal links as:

```
<a href='http://example.com/def' title='abc'>Abc</a>
```

or

```
<a hef='/def' title='abc'>Abc</a>
```

I know that linking would be same but what to know the impact on SEO the internal link way there are written.

Answer (score 2):

Providing you are already canonicalising the requested URL (eg. HTTPS and www subdomain etc.) and the `base` tag (if any) refers to the canonical URL then, in terms of SEO, it makes no difference whether you are using root-relative or absolute URLs in your HTML source.

Any search engine spider must resolve partial URLs to be absolute, so ultimately there is no difference.

Comment: why https://www.seowebpageanalyzer.com/ putting weight to internal links and other seo sites

Comment: @Vineet1982 I'm not sure what you mean? Do you have an example? What does that have to do with root-relative vs absolute URLs in links?

Answer (score 2):

These two methods of internal linking do the exact same thing, so I don't see any reason why Google would weight these differently. I've not seen any evidence of a difference for SEO.

That said, the second method has the potential to exacerbate an already existing problem if you are not properly 301 redirecting http to https and non-www to www (or vice versa).

As your website evolves, for example, you may have old links pointing to the http:// when you're now using https:// or non-www if you're using www now. But as long as you're redirecting properly then those older internal links will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I Think there is no big difference if you don't change the URLs and structure very often. For bigger pages like E-Commerce shops with a high intensity of changing URL structures root-relative URLs are better for the handling not for the SEO. It depends on the domain and the system